# Syius smtp mail

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, sylius

I want to setup smtp mail for [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius), I set all mail parameters but it doesn't work(verification email and reset-password email not sent).

Comment: Well, are you sure that your parameters for smtp are okay? Have you checked with Gmail configuration maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on dev environment, you should disable in config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: false
```

Did you do it?
And yes, Sylius is using SwiftMailer as you see above.